# Argon2 malloc access violation exception

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to use Argon2 library from https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-winner-argon2 and below is my code in C++. The following is a simple class constructed in c++ using the c-level api in the Argon2 Library.

```
#include "argon2.h"

#include <string>

#define HASHLEN 32
#define SALTLEN 16
#define ENCODED_LEN 108
#define PWD "password"

class Argon2Exception : public std::exception
{
public:
    Argon2Exception(std::string message) : _message(message) { }

    const char * what () const throw () {
       return _message.c_str();
    }
    
private:
    std::string _message;
};

class Argon2
{
public:
    Argon2() { }
    ~Argon2() { }

    std::string gen_hash(std::string pwd, std::string salt)
    {
        if (salt.size() > SALTLEN)
            throw Argon2Exception("Salt size exceeds default size of bytes.");

        //
        // ARGON2_PUBLIC int argon2_hash(const uint32_t t_cost, const uint32_t m_cost,
                              // const uint32_t parallelism, const void *pwd,
                              // const size_t pwdlen, const void *salt,
                              // const size_t saltlen, void *hash,
                              // const size_t hashlen, char *encoded,
                              // const size_t encodedlen, argon2_type type,
                              // const uint32_t version);
        int rc = argon2_hash(_t_cost, _m_cost, _parallelism, pwd.c_str(),
             pwd.size(), salt.c_str(), SALTLEN, _hash1, HASHLEN,
             _encoded, ENCODED_LEN, Argon2_i, ARGON2_VERSION_10);
        
        if (rc != ARGON2_OK)
            throw Argon2Exception("Argon2 hash was not created successfully.");
        
        std::string hash;
        for (int i = 0; i < HASHLEN; i++) {
            char fbuf[4];
            snprintf(fbuf, 4, "%02x", _hash1[i]);
            hash.append(1, fbuf[0]);
            hash.append(1, fbuf[1]);
        }
        return hash;
    }
    
    bool verify(std::string hash1, std::string pwd, std::string salt)
    {
        if (salt.size() > SALTLEN)
            throw Argon2Exception("Salt size exceeds default size of bytes.");
        
        std::string hash2 = gen_hash(pwd, salt);
        
        if (memcmp(hash1.data(), hash2.data(), HASHLEN * 2) == 0)
            return true;
        
        return false;
    }
    
private:
    uint8_t _hash1[HASHLEN]{ '\0' };
    uint32_t _t_cost{2},    // 1-pass computation
        _m_cost{(1<<16)},   // 64 megabytes memory usage
        _parallelism{1};    // number of threads and lanes 
    char _encoded[ENCODED_LEN]{ '\0' };
};
```

I am presented with the following error on running a test program created with Boost.Test -

[image: Argon2 Access Violation Exception]

The code works without errors on macOS but has this issue on Windows 10 Visual Studio 16. Looking for someone to review my code and help me narrow down on a solution to the problem.

Comment: There are a few things wrong with your question: Firstly, provide a [mcve]. Then, decide for one programming language (looks like C++, even if parts of the code are C). Lastly, replace the picture of an error message with text, because only then people can search for that text online and locate similar issues.

Comment: Seems to me the question is as formed as it can be - included is the code and a picture of the visual studio failure with a callstack.  I would double check if this was build as "debug" to be sure the compiler is giving you all it can.  The disassembly view will also show you why it decided to jump to a strange address as `malloc` from the watch window is a different address than the crash.  Time to really dig into the debugger.